# window.onload doesnt run the assigned (scroll) function

Tags: javascript, ajax, scroll, chat

I am building an AJAX chat system in vanilla Javascript and AJAX (so no jQuery). The messages are loaded via AJAX and put in a div that uses `overflow-y: scroll;`  so you can scroll through all the messages.

Because the latest messages appear at the bottom I have a scrollDown()  function that scrolls to the end of the div:

```
function scrollDown()
{
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbox");
}
```

The problem is that this function does not work. If I do `window.onload = function() { scrollDown(); };` I also tried `window.onload =  scrollDown` but that doesnt work either.

I am sure that problem isnt in the scrollDown() function because I also use the function to scroll down automatically when a new message appears, then it works great.

Here is my complete source code:

```
getBerichten();

function getHTTPObject(){
   if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
   else {
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
      return null;
   }
}   

function doWork(id, user_id) {    
    nieuwbericht = getHTTPObject();
    if (nieuwbericht != null) {

        if( document.getElementById('bericht').value != "")
        {

        nieuwbericht.open("GET", "ajaxberichten.php?id=" + id + "&user_id=" + user_id + "&bericht="
                        + document.getElementById('bericht').value, true);

        nieuwbericht.send(null); 
        document.getElementById("bericht").value = "";
        }
    }
}

function setOutput()
{
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
            //scrollDown();
            setInterval(getBerichten(),1000);
    }
}

function getBerichten()
{
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();

    if (httpObject != null) 
    {
        httpObject.open("GET", "ajaxgetberichten.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>", true);

        httpObject.send(null);
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }
}

function scrollDown()
{
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbox");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}

window.onload = function() { scrollDown(); };
```

My html page:

```
<div class="postbox">

    <div class="post">

        <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox">
            <div id="berichten"></div>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <textarea name="bericht" id="bericht"rows="20" cols="85"> </textarea>
            <input name="verstuur" type="button" onclick="doWork(<?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>, <?php echo $user_id ?>);" value="Verstuur"/>
        </form>  

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try document.ready() instead of window.onload(), as you DOM can be not ready on window event

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I still have the same problem. Its interesting because when I open the page in a new tab it works. If I load the page and then reload it again by using F5 it doesnt work anymore.